# How to get a tooltip working within a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am following this tooltip tutorial on youtube `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqKrCQcsaAA` and thought I had it nailed but when I use the tooltip function it is deleting my input box.

here is my code:

```
<input type="text" name="pword1" class="iBox" id="pword1" autocomplete="off"  onmouseout="HideToolTip()" onmouseover="ShowToolTip()" onkeyup="reqMetVal()" placeholder="choose a password" >

function ShowToolTip(){
    document.getElementById("pword1").style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function HideToolTip(){
    document.getElementById("pword1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

and then when i fire it up into the browser to test it, when i hover over the input box it disappears and can only enter into it by refreshing the page and tabbing into it

Comment: How about just using the title attribute for tool tip.  http://jsfiddle.net/rm807wd6/

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to do is *understand* what the code is doing. The way you are right now, you could blindly copy and paste a backdoor right into your website and find your server hacked, and you would have no idea what you did. (This is the reason recent "social.png" hacks have been so common lately).

The functional parts of your code are:

- `onmouseout="HideToolTip()"`
- `onmouseover="ShowToolTip()"`

`HideToolTip` gets the element with ID `pword1` and hides it. `pword1` is your input element, as shown by the `id="pword1"` attribute in your code.

So basically, when you move the mouse out of the box, it disappears. You can't `mouseover` a hidden element, so there's no way to get it back.

It's impossible to tell from your question exactly what you intended to do, but perhaps this is it?

```js
function ShowToolTip(){
    document.getElementById("tooltipbox").style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function HideToolTip(){
    document.getElementById("tooltipbox").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="pword1" class="iBox" id="pword1" autocomplete="off"  onmouseout="HideToolTip()" onmouseover="ShowToolTip()" onkeyup="reqMetVal()" placeholder="choose a password" >
<p id="tooltipbox" style="visibility:hidden">This is the tooltip</p>
```

Comment: fantastic. thanks. that works well. i do understand what the code is doing. i am new to JavaScript though and whilst simultaneously learning that I am trying to build my rep on here and learn Java and Spring. so forgive me when I don't quite get it right.